# How can I get jobs to show up on Google Job search

Tags: google

Hi I have a client who wants there jobs to show up on Google job search.

They currently have a vacancy page which is built with ninja forms - and from research, it doesn't look like this can be changed so that it has the structured data so that it shows up on Google job search.

I've had a look at this but uncertain how to do this in WordPress:

https://www.betterteam.com/google-for-jobs

Looking through it seems like a plugin such as:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/job-postings/

Might do the job.

If anyone has any experience or guidance on this it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

At first glance you don't seem to have the structured data that google requires. 
The full documentation is at: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/job-posting#definitions

As far as I can see, your website does not have a single page for each job posting. The structure data requires that. (As far as I can see the listing there lead to individual different sites, which are outside your control).

No experience with the plugin you are quoting, but at first glance it seems to satisfy the "works with google jobs", so in your case I would give it a try.